# Optimal IP range for private LAN network

Tags: ipv4, subnet, ip, lan

working on small LAN for a office, going to use windows server 2012 with AD which ip range is suitable for this. there's like 13pc's & 1 server

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the private address ranges are acceptable:

```
10.0.0.0/8
172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0/16
```

Which you choose is up to you since any are larger than you need right now, but you may want to think about future growth, too.

Comment: in future there's only be like 10-20  pc's more. is it necessary to subnet even my network is a small one?

Comment: You probably want to pick a much larger size. Many people use `/24` as the default since it is easier for them, and it is a reasonable size for a VLAN. Just understand that you should be thinking about the _future_ where you could be 10 times your predicted size. That is one of the biggest mistakes companies seem to make, and the choices you make now can have big consequences in the future. If you wait until it gets out of hand, then you must reconfigure everything.

Comment: i see, so what will be you personal choice for a basic LAN? this network i am implementing for a web development firm

Comment: You could pick a `/24` as your basic VLAN size. The `192.168.0.0/16` is fairly limited (256 VLANs) with that size. I would personally use the `10.0.0.0/8` and start with `/24` VLANs, and there is plenty of room for bigger VLANs if you end up with something like a data center in the future. It's no fun having to manually re-address statically addressed devices like servers and printers, even if there are only a few, and get everyone to point to the new addresses.

Answer (score 1):

As Ron Maupin already mentioned, anything in those three ranges defined in [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) will be fine, those are assigned for local networks.

Personally, I wouldn't pick one of the more obvious ranges like `192.168.0.0/24` or `10.0.0.0/24` if you ever plan to offer services like VPN for remote workers. Most of the home routers use those by default for their local networks, so it can be wise to stay clear of ranges to prevent an overlap.

I'd pick a range from the `172.16.0.0/12` network (which seems to be less used in home routers), and not the first `/24`, so for example `172.31.0.0/24`.